# Localizable.strings not found at runtime

Tags: ios, localization, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, localizable.strings

I develop ios application (iPhone) in MonoTouch(5.2.12)/MonoDevelop(3.0.3.2)

I tried to localize it.

I created localization folders (de.lproj)(Add->New folder) and I placed 'Localizable.strings' file there. This file was added to project (Add->Add files ...).

Localization doesn't work.
I find out that localization files (Localizable.strings) don't locate in runtime place
(/user/jpa/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/A99 ...B13/MyApp.app/de.lproj/), even though in MonoDevelop they are.

Why? What is wrong? File is UTF-8 coded. (It doesn't depict with UTF-16)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll need to set the build action of your files to "Content" (right click file -> Build Action -> Content).

Answer (score 1):

How do you call your Localized string ? Can you give us a piece of code ?

You don't need to create manually the localization folders, just:

- create a `Localizable.string` file (Right click in project explorer then "New File")
- select it
- open the Xcode right panel (if not already open)
- click on + in the Localization part, and select the language

This method will prevent from manipulation errors because Xcode create the localization folders itself.

Comment: partial void actClick (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender) {<br />
  lblEnvir.Text = NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier;
  lblJazyk.Text = NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[0];
  lblPath.Text = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("heron","jpg");

  this.lblOutput.Text = 
    NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("stisk", "pressed") + " " +
    ((UIButton)sender).CurrentTitle + " " + 
    NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("tlac", "button");
}